# Why .NET Core introduced Autofac since it has dependency control system?

Tags: .net, autofac

I know in old .NET we used to have Autofac and injector net ?

But why .NET Core still maintaing Autofac?

https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html

We can dependency Using

addsingleton vs addscoped vs addtransient

Any reason ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autofac is a library which existed long before .NET Core so migrating it makes sense at least for the sake of easier migration of projects  already using it. Also it is not maintained by Microsoft and/or team developing .NET Core (see the [github project](https://github.com/orgs/autofac/people)).

Autofac supports more features then build in DI, which misses things like ([see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement)):

> The built-in service container is designed to serve the needs of the framework and most consumer apps. We recommend using the built-in container unless you need a specific feature that it doesn't support, such as:

> - Property injection
> - Injection based on name
> - Child containers
> - Custom lifetime management
> - Func support for lazy initialization
> - Convention-based registration

Comment: Storm, conditional injection, please corrrect me if I am wrong

Comment: @user123456 what do you mean?

Comment: for example, let u say you have IcacheService, and you have 2 implemntation. Radis, and Mmemory, u want on run time to conditionaly select one. Using autoface you can do that. Can I do that in .net core depenedcy internal system ?

Comment: @user123456 AFAIK this achieved in autofac with keyed dependencies which, I assume, fall under _Injection based on name_ category, so no.

Comment: I was emphizing this to make sure I undesratnd what u mean